# Can I mirror animations on bones?

Tags: animation, bones, mirror

I have a model of a dragon. It's mesh was made by mirroring and also was it's bones. I want to animate a wing, but want to make the other wing to animate equally, but mirrored. Is it possible?
I'm new to blender, so I need a bit more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 9):

Try copying the pose, then pasting x-mirrored= <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

You can copy the pose in the pose menu, right next to the mode changing button.

See the one that says **Pose**?

[image]

Once you copy a pose (*Copy Pose*) you can either *paste pose* or *paste x-flipped pose.*

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but how/where can I copy the pose and how do I paste it?